# Kohana 3 - SphinxQL Configuration

Tags: php, kohana, sphinx

I have Sphinx up and running on my server and I have created an index of my data.  I have installed SphinxQL into my modules folder and enabled it in my bootstrap.  Is there something else that I need to have done or to do to?  I have also moved a copy of the sphinxql.php config file into the kohana/application/config directory but I may not have the correct settings there.

Thank you very much to anyone trying to help!

```
return array(
    'default' => array(
        'servers' => array(         
            'home' => 'localhost:9312',         
            // Key => Value
            //'<server a name>' => '<host>:<port>',
            //'<server b name>' => '<host>:<port>',

            // For example
            //'sphinx_01' => '192.168.1.1:9301',
            //'sphinx_02' => '192.168.1.2:9301',
            //'sphinx_03' => '192.168.1.3:9301',

            // ...or...
            //'sphinx_first' => '192.168.1.1:1234',
            //'sphinx_second' => '123.45.67.89:8765',

            // ...or!
            //'my_only_server' => '127.0.0.1:2222',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Here is my query I am running to try to return the ids of the documents with the term 'searchterm' within.

```
$sphinxql = new SphinxQL();
$query    = $sphinxql->new_query();

$query->add_index('indexname')->search('searchterm');

$result = $query->execute();
```

Comment: Please show some code/settings

Comment: Just added the default config file, that's what I have.  Not quite sure how to configure it because I don't think it's just localhost...

Comment: Also included basic code snippet of trying to use SphinxQL

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kohana_Database_MySQL to build your SphinxQL wrapper with some small changes.